# Find specific comments in HTML code using python

Tags: python

I cant find a specific comment in python, in example the `<!-- why -->`.
My main reason is to find all the links inside 2 specific comments. Something like a parser.
I tried this with `Beautifulsoup` :

```
import urllib
over=urlopen("www.gamespot.com").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(over)
print soup.find("<!--why-->")
```

But it doesn't work. 
I think I might have to use `regex` and not `Beautifulsoup`.

Please help.

EXAMPLE: 
we have HTML Code like this

```
<!--why-->
www.godaddy.com
<p> nice one</p>
www.wwf.com
<!-- why not-->
```

**EDIT: Between the 2 comments, other stuff, like tags, might exist.**

And I need to store all the links .

Comment: Give a real example, that will help everyone.

Answer (score 6):

If you want all the comments, you can use `findAll` with a callable:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
>>> 
>>> s = """
... <p>header</p>
... <!-- why -->
... www.test1.com
... www.test2.org
... <!-- why not -->
... <p>tail</p>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> comments = soup.findAll(text = lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
>>> 
>>> comments
[u' why ', u' why not ']
```

And once you've got them, you can use the usual tricks to move around:

```
>>> comments[0].next
u'\nwww.test1.com\nwww.test2.org\n'
>>> comments[0].next.split()
[u'www.test1.com', u'www.test2.org']
```

Depending on what the page actually looks like, you may have to tweak it a bit, and you'll have to choose which comments you want, but that should work to get you started.

Edit:

If you really want only the ones which look like some specific text, you can do something like

```
>>> comments = soup.findAll(text = lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and text.strip() == 'why')
>>> comments
[u' why ']
```

or you could filter them after the fact using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [c for c in comments if c.strip().startswith("why")]
[u' why ', u' why not ']
```

Comment: Nice solution! I didn't realize I have to import `Comment` and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The source code might have a lot of comment-blocks. I need to search only for the ones that start with 'why'. Does this work in this way?

Comment: @georgemano: I've edited it.  It might be worthwhile reading through a Python tutorial -- there are lots of ways to do neat things which are easy once you know them but are hard to guess.

Comment: @georgemano: you've now asked three different questions with three slightly different answers.  Respectfully, that's not the best way to get help.

Comment: It is not my goal to make you suffer or to make you trouble. My goal is to learn things that I cant understand.

Comment: @DSM So, you know the solution and you don't want to share it?