# Split html document in pieces parsing html comments with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

This is a pretty small question that has been almost resolved [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12774067/982901%20in%20a%20previous%20thread).

Problem is that right now i have and array of comments, but it does not quite what I need. I get an array of comments-content. And I need to get the html in-between.

Say I have something like:

```
<p>some html here<p>
<!-- begin mark -->
<p>Html i'm interested at.</p>
<p>More html i want to pull out of the document.</p>
<!-- end mark -->
<!-- begin mark -->
<p>This will be pulled later, but we will come to it when I get to pull the previous section.</p>
<!-- end mark -->
```

In a reply, they point to [Crummy explanation on navigating the html tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Searching%20the%20Parse%20Tree), but I didnt find there and answer to my problem.

Any ideas? Thanks.

PS. Extra kudos if someone point me an elegant way to repeat the process a few times in a document, as I probably may get it to work, but poorly :D

Edited to add:

With the information provided by Martijn Pieters, I got to pass the `comments` array obtained using the above code to the generator function he designed. So this gives no error:

```
for elem in comments:
    htmlcode = allnext(comments)
    print htmlcode
```

I think now it will be possible to manipulate the htmlcode content before iterating through the array.

Comment: Note that BeautifulSoup puts `<p>` tags *around* each comment in your example.

Comment: I'm new to BeautifulSoup, I will pay attention to this :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.next_sibling` pointer to get to the next element. You can use that to find everything *following* a comment, up to but not including another comment:

```
from bs4 import Comment

def allnext(comment):
    curr = comment
    while True:
        curr = curr.next_sibling
        if isinstance(curr, Comment):
            return
        yield curr
```

This is a generator function, you use it to iterate over all 'next' elements:

```
for elem in allnext(comment):
    print elem
```

or you can use it to create a list of all next elements:

```
elems = list(allnext(comment))
```

Your example is a little too small for BeautifulSoup and it'll wrap each comment in a `<p>` tag but if we use a snippet from your original target `www.gamespot.com` this works just fine:

```
<div class="ad_wrap ad_wrap_dart"><div style="text-align:center;"><img alt="Advertisement" src="http://ads.com.com/Ads/common/advertisement.gif" style="display:block;height:10px;width:120px;margin:0 auto;"/></div>
<!-- start of gamespot gpt ad tag -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1359295192-lb-top">
<script type="text/javascript">
        googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1359295192-lb-top');
    </script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/jump?iu=/6975/row/gamespot.com/home&amp;sz=728x90|970x66|970x150|970x250|960x150&amp;t=pos%3Dtop%26platform%3Ddesktop%26&amp;c=1359295192">
<img src="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ad?iu=/6975/row/gamespot.com/home&amp;sz=728x90|970x66|970x150|970x250|960x150&amp;t=pos%3Dtop%26platform%3Ddesktop%26&amp;c=1359295192"/>
</a>
</noscript>
</div>
<!-- end of gamespot gpt tag -->
</div>
```

If `comment` is a reference to the first comment in that snippet, the `allnext()` generator gives me:

```
>>> list(allnext(comment))
[u'\n', <div id="div-gpt-ad-1359295192-lb-top">
<script type="text/javascript">
        googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1359295192-lb-top');
    </script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/jump?iu=/6975/row/gamespot.com/home&amp;sz=728x90|970x66|970x150|970x250|960x150&amp;t=pos%3Dtop%26platform%3Ddesktop%26&amp;c=1359295192">
<img src="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ad?iu=/6975/row/gamespot.com/home&amp;sz=728x90|970x66|970x150|970x250|960x150&amp;t=pos%3Dtop%26platform%3Ddesktop%26&amp;c=1359295192"/>
</a>
</noscript>
</div>, u'\n']
```

Comment: I tried the small for loop, just printing every allnext ouput. It says that `"curr" doesn't have a next_sibling attribute`. Other variations like nextSibling yield the same error. This happens also in the snippet you suggested from the original target gamespot.com.

Comment: @versvs: I tested with BeautifulSoup 4, do you use an older version?

Comment: @versvs: In BeautifulSoup 3 it is `.nextSibling` instead but it may be that that doesn't work for comments in 3. Can you upgrade to 4 instead?

Comment: I'm using beautifulsoup 4 for Python 2. May the problem be that i'm stuck in python2?

Comment: @versvs: strange; I tested this on python 2.7. What does `type(comment)` tell you you have?

Comment: it says `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`

Comment: @versvs: So you have *all* the comments. Loop over that result set and pass *those* to the function.

Comment: yup... but when i try to loop (simple loop `print elem`) it says next_sibling isnt there :S

Comment: @versvs: And what does `print type(elem)` say?

Comment: i'm editing my question cause i think i found the error... :D

Comment: @versvs: Why are you matching against comments, btw? On the `gamespot.com` page the comments only precede `<div>` tags with ids that can be matched using a regular expression instead: `soup.findall('div', {'id': re.compile('^div-gpt-ad-')})`

Comment: I have a large html file that contains a book (hundreds of chapters...) to be formatted into epub and has comments that mark the begin and end of every single chapter :)