# Downloading Images with Beautifulsoup without HTML 'img' tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im using beautifulsoup to find and download images from a given website, however the website contains images which aren't in the usual `<img src="icon.gif"/>` format:

The ones that are causing me problems for example are like this :

`<form action="example.jpg">`

`<!-- <img src="big.jpg" /> -->`

`background-image:url("xine.png");`

My code to find the images is:

```
webpage = "https://example.com/images/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(webpage), "html.parser")

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    img_url = urljoin(webpage, img['src'])
    file_name = img['src'].split('/')[-1]
    file_path = os.path.join("C:\\users\\images", file_name)
    urlretrieve(img_url, file_path)
```

I think i might have to use a regex but hopefully i don't have to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use full path `urlretrieve(img_url, "c:\files\cw\downloads\" + file_name)`

Answer (score 1):

Modify the path you pass to [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html) to specify exactly where you want the file to be copied to:

```
file_path = os.path.join('c:\files\cw\downloads', file_name)
urlretrieve(img_url, file_path)
```

Edit:
It looks like you are also trying to find `img` tags inside comments. Building off of [Find specific comments in HTML code using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773921/find-specific-comments-in-html-code-using-python):

```
...
imgs = soup.find_all('img')
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))
for comment in comments:
    comment_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(comment)
    imgs.extend(comment_soup.findAll('img'))

for img in imgs:
    ...
```