# How Save image when there is no exact src for image attribute?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I want to crawl and save image from some page which the page source is this: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAP3j.png)

I tried several python libraries to save this image like scrappy and selenium but because of src of image they didn't work correctly!

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://example.com/aportal/')
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img")
src = img.get_attribute('src')
urllib.urlretrieve(src, "test.jpeg")
```

What is the correct way to download images like this?

Comment: Somehow the html within the _screenshot_ and _url_ doesn't matches

Comment: I tried several ways to download the image, the screenshot is for when i open img in new tab and run the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541274/downloading-images-with-beautifulsoup-without-html-img-tag

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to rich the element of the image:

You can use `driver.save_screenshot("path/to/save/image.png")`

Hope this helps!